# C# MySQL Parameterized Query Problem

Tags: c#, mysql

I have the following method which is used to populate a DAO from the database. It performs 3 reads - one for the primary object, and 2 for some translations.

```
public bool read(string id, MySqlConnection c)
{
    MySqlCommand m = new MySqlCommand(readCommand);
    m.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@param1", id));
    m.Connection = c;
    MySqlDataReader r = m.ExecuteReader();
    r.Read();
    accountID = Convert.ToInt32(r.GetValue(0).ToString());
    ...
    comment = r.GetValue(8).ToString();
    r.Close();
    m = new MySqlCommand(getAccountName);
    m.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@param1", accountID));
    m.Connection = c;
    r = m.ExecuteReader();
    r.Read();
    account1Name = r.GetValue(0).ToString();
    r.Close();
    m = new MySqlCommand(getAccountName);
    m.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@param1", secondAccountID));
    m.Connection = c;
    r = m.ExecuteReader();
    r.Read();
    account2Name = r.GetValue(0).ToString();
    r.Close();
    return true;
}
```

On the line `account2Name = r.GetValue(0).ToString();` I get the following error:

```
Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()
```

I don't understand what the problem is - the previous line calls read!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to be working earlier in your code.  Are you sure there is a value to read there (i.e. is your query returning 0 rows or null or something else that can't be converted to a string?)

Answer (score 1):

1. Looks like that procedure works fine on the line `account1Name = r.GetValue(0).ToString();`. Maybe you want to check the return value of `r.Read()` to see if there are any rows first. The error could be interpreted as "Attempted to access a field without data"...
2. It looks like you're trying to get a single value out of a query. You might want to look into the `ExecuteScalar()` method instead of `ExecuteReader()`.